# Python __index__ and evaluation order

Tags: python

I was expecting the two code below to return the same result because of https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order. However it looks like `__index__` from Counter class is called after `__call__` in the second case. Is it because `__index__` gets called only when reaching `]` ? Or is there another explanation ?

```python
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self._i = start

    def __call__(self, step:int=None):
        if step is not None:
            self._i += step
        return self._i

    def __index__(self):
        return self._i

data = list(range(0, 10))
```

```
i = Counter(0)
data[i():i(3)]
```

returns `[0, 1, 2]`

```
i = Counter(0)
data[i:i(3)]
```

returns `[]`

PS: The goal of the Counter class is to allow assignment like syntax in python < 3.8

```
i = 0
data[i: (i := i+3)]
```

Comment: Yes, `__index__` doesn't get called until `data.__getitem__` is being executed, which is *after* `Counter.__call__` is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data[i:i(3)]` is equivalent to `data.__getitem__(slice(i, i(3)))`; `i.__index__` doesn't get called until the starting element of the slice is actually needed, inside the body of `data.__getitem__`, but after `i(3)` has already incremented `i._step` to 3. So the order of evaluation is something like:

1. `data[i:i(3)]`
2. Evaluate `i(3)` to 3
3. Build the slice `slice(i,3)`
4. Inside `data.__getitem__`, the integer value of `i` is needed, so `i.__index__` is called, which returns 3.

You can see this by disassembling the indexing operation:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('data[i:i(3)]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (data)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (3)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 BUILD_SLICE              2
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

First `i(3)` is called (at offset 8), then the slice is built (at offset 10), and finally `data.__getitem__` is called (at offset 12).